# Calculate Running Count in Power BI based on two column context evaluation

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I have a column called Weekly User Escalation which is a binary column indicating whether a user has been escalated or not in a specific calendar week. 1 for yes, 0 for no.

The data's granularity is dates (in one calendar week dates can also be missing and not always equal 7 days). So, for any calendar week, I can have 1-7 rows in my dataset.

Now, I want a column which sums up the escalation levels per user per CW. I.e., if User 1 has been escalated in Calendar Week 1 and 2 and not in CW 3, it should return 1+1+0=2, and so on.

What I tried already is this:

```
CALCULATE(SUMX('Data', MAX('Data'[Weekly User Escalation])), ALLEXCEPT('Data', 'Data'[User], 'Data'[Calendar Week]))
```

The output shows the sum of all the 1s and 0s in for that user, which in my case shows 13, since there were 13 rows which were "1" for a particular CW in my dataset. I want that only the MAX value from the column Weekly User Escalation, which is always 1, is counted AND ONLY ONCE for every CW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
 WeekWithEscalation =   CALCULATE( Countrows( VALUES('Data'[Calendar Week]), 'Data'[Weekly User Escalation] = 1 )
```

If we put to visualization UserName and measure [WeekWithEscalation] that should work.